# High value weed or plant that can replace the chemical treatment of pesticides and herbicides?

Tags: botany, ecology, agriculture

I'm working on a project that aims to replace (at least lower) the use of chemical pesticides and herbicides in farming with the use of high value weeds and plants that can naturally replace the chemical treatment.  So for example , if hedgerows (the edges of the field or the surrounding of a crop) made with high value weeds can be incorporated to fixate nitrogen, or to help the crop fight and resist a given disease, or maybe have a positive impact on the crop, etc...

My mission is : to build a database with high value weeds and plants, and their effects. For example the database should look like :

| High value weed | effect |
| --- | --- |
| x | fixate nitrogen |
| y | help crop fight disease d |
| z | effect z |

I'm looking for any already existing database, research or any resource that tackle something like this.
Note: I'm not an expert in farming , I'm just a data science student dealing with agriculture related problems. So please forgive my ignorance. I would be very happy to learn.

Comment: Your issue is not knowing proper terminology and using wrong terminology. Some search terms: cover crops, legumes, biological nitrification inhibitors, crop sequences, undersowing, ... You need to talk to a domain expert.